# wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-i18n, ruby-3

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def t(*a)
    translate(*a)
  end
end
```

**Case 1 :**- `t('views.home.welcome_updated', default: 'Updated')` => Getting Error: (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))

**Case 2 :**- `t('views.welcome')`  => Working fine

```
Ruby Version: 3.0.6
Rails Version: 6.1.7.6
```

What is the problem with above code?

Both case 1 & 2 working fine in ruby 2.7. i am getting error after upgraded ruby version to 3

customize t method to

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def t(key, **options)
    args = [key]
    args.push options if options.present?
    translate(*a)
  end
end
```

But this is also not working

Comment: The method's signature is `translate(key, **options)` but your `*a` only captures positional arguments, i.e. the `key` part. In Ruby 3.x, you have to handle [keyword arguments](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments) explicitly via `**` or use `...` as shown below.

Comment: BTW, Rails' [`TranslationHelper`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html) defines both, `translate` and `t`, so maybe you already have both variants and are needlessly re-defining `t`.

Answer (score 4):

When you want to forward all arguments, not matter of their structure, then you can use the [`...` syntax](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/12/04/ruby-2-7-adds-new-operator-for-arguments-forwarding/), like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def t(...)
    translate(...)
  end
end
```

Or, when do not need to manipulate the arguments before forwarding to the original method or to act on the response before returning, then you can alias the method name like this:

```
alias_method :t, :translate
```